# Rails - Logical Operator on Scopes, is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, scopes

I have a class that represents a game (match) with 2 scopes:

```
  scope :home_lineuped, ->() { includes(:home_lineup).where(home_lineup: {lineuped: true }) }
  scope :away_lineuped, ->() { includes(:away_lineup).where(away_lineup: {lineuped: true }) }
```

I would like to create a new scope with the logical operator *Not And* on the results, is it possible?

**EDIT:** What do I mean?

Imagine that:
`Match.All` gives me matches with ID, *1, 2, 3, 4, 5* and *6*;

`Match.home_lineuped` gives me matches with ID, *1, 2* and *6*;

`Match.away_lineuped` gives me matches with ID  *3, 4* and *6*;

The result of: `(Match.home_lineuped AND Match.away_lineuped)` is: *6*.

Therefore: `Not (Match.home_lineuped AND Match.away_lineuped)` will result in matches with ID: *1, 2, 3, 4,* and *5*.

**End EDIT**

Best Regards,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your meaning are `Match.home_lineuped & Match.away_lineuped` and `Match.all -  (Match.home_lineuped & Match.away_lineuped)`.

Or create new scope

`scope :home_lineuped_and_away_lineuped, ->() { includes(:home_lineup, :away_lineup).where(home_lineups: {lineuped: true }, away_lineups: {lineuped: true }) }`

`scope :not_home_lineuped_and_away_lineuped, ->() { includes(:home_lineup, :away_lineup).where.not(home_lineups: {lineuped: true }, away_lineups: {lineuped: true }) }`

Comment: `scope` is just syntactic sugar for declaring class methods. If your method does not fit in a one liner lambda then use normal class method definition for readability. Multi-line scopes are a code smell.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of Rails you are using ActiveRecord does have a [`not`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain/not) method. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm on Rails 5.2, could you give me an example?

Comment: @DavidSousa Beyond the examples from the link?

Answer (score 1):

```
scope :home_lineuped, -> { includes(:home_lineup).where(home_lineup: {lineuped: true }) }
scope :away_lineuped, -> { includes(:away_lineup).where(away_lineup: {lineuped: true }) }
```

You can call one scope after other for AND logic like this:

```
Match.home_lineuped.away_lineuped
```

But if you need scope, you can unite two scopes as:

```
scope :home_and_lineuped, -> do
  includes(:home_lineup, :away_lineup).
    where(home_lineup: {lineuped: true }, away_lineup: {lineuped: true })
end
```

And for opposite logic (NOT AND) you can use [`not`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-not):

```
scope :no_home_away_lineuped, -> do
  includes(:home_lineup, :away_lineup).
    where.not(home_lineup: {lineuped: true }, away_lineup: {lineuped: true })
end
```